# Repeat a series n time in order

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, repeat, series

I have a series of data for 24 hours and need to extend it for the whole year in such a way that the value related to each hour repeat 365 times (for example the value of 1.a.m = 0.256 I need this value to repeat 365 times but in a specific order before 2 a.m and after 12 a.m.)
The output I needed for example for only 2 repeats:
(0,1,2,3,....23,0,1,2,3,....23)
I do not need something like this:
(0,0,1,1,2,2,.....23,23)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a repeating sequence, you can do this -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(3)

R = np.repeat(X[None, :], 5, axis=0).reshape(15)

print(R)
```

Gives -

```
[0 1 2]
[0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2]
```

`R` is what you are looking for

Comment: I tried this one. The problem is that it repeats each data 365 times not in the order that I wanted. I want series of 24 values repeated in the same exact order. The output of your function would be (0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,.....23,23) for n = 2 for exampe. Instead I need something like this: (0,1,2,3,....23,0,1,2,3,....23)

Comment: Did you try the exact code I posted? It's meant to handle exactly that case. I edited with the output also posted. It does produce the output that you specified.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `np.tile` ?

```
import numpy as np

# Your array
l = np.array([0,1,2,3])

# Number of repeats
n = 10

# Final array
r = np.tile(l, n)
```

Answer (score 1):

The list type is additive in Python, so

```
print([1,2,3] + [1,2,3])
```

Gives output

```
[1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

Multiplication by an integer just adds the list to itself that many times, so

```
print([1,2,3]*3)
```

Gives output

```
[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

So you want `list(range(24))*365` to get your time stamps and `list(your_data)*365` to get your data values